# Cannot get MNIST database through Anaconda/jupyter

Tags: scikit-learn, anaconda, jupyter

Hu guys,

I'm new to python/anaconda/jupyter/numPy, panda, etc.... so please excuse me if it's a really stupid question.
I'm trying to obtain MNIST database by using anaconda/jupyter. But everytime I get an HTTP error 500 at the end. Is it really a server problem (as 500 would suggest) or am I doing something wrong?

Input in jupyter:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_mldata
mnist = fetch_mldata('MNIST original')
```

Result:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-1-15dc285fb373> in <module>()
          1 from sklearn.datasets import fetch_mldata
    ----> 2 mnist = fetch_mldata('MNIST original')

    e:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\datasets\mldata.py in fetch_mldata(dataname, target_name, data_name, transpose_data, data_home)
        140         urlname = MLDATA_BASE_URL % quote(dataname)
        141         try:
    --> 142             mldata_url = urlopen(urlname)
        143         except HTTPError as e:
        144             if e.code == 404:

    e:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
        221     else:
        222         opener = _opener
    --> 223     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
        224 
        225 def install_opener(opener):

    e:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
        530         for processor in self.process_response.get(protocol, []):
        531             meth = getattr(processor, meth_name)
    --> 532             response = meth(req, response)
        533 
        534         return response

    e:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in http_response(self, request, response)
        640         if not (200 <= code < 300):
        641             response = self.parent.error(
    --> 642                 'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
        643 
        644         return response

    e:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in error(self, proto, *args)
        562             http_err = 0
        563         args = (dict, proto, meth_name) + args
    --> 564         result = self._call_chain(*args)
        565         if result:
        566             return result

    e:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in _call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
        502         for handler in handlers:
        503             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
    --> 504             result = func(*args)
        505             if result is not None:
        506                 return result

    e:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in http_error_302(self, req, fp, code, msg, headers)
        754         fp.close()
        755 
    --> 756         return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
        757 
        758     http_error_301 = http_error_303 = http_error_307 = http_error_302

    e:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
        530         for processor in self.process_response.get(protocol, []):
        531             meth = getattr(processor, meth_name)
    --> 532             response = meth(req, response)
        533 
        534         return response

    e:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in http_response(self, request, response)
        640         if not (200 <= code < 300):
        641             response = self.parent.error(
    --> 642                 'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
        643 
        644         return response

    e:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in error(self, proto, *args)
        568         if http_err:
        569             args = (dict, 'default', 'http_error_default') + orig_args
    --> 570             return self._call_chain(*args)
        571 
        572 # XXX probably also want an abstract factory that knows when it makes

    e:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in _call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
        502         for handler in handlers:
        503             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
    --> 504             result = func(*args)
        505             if result is not None:
        506                 return result

    e:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
        648 class HTTPDefaultErrorHandler(BaseHandler):
        649     def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
    --> 650         raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
        651 
        652 class HTTPRedirectHandler(BaseHandler):

    HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: INTERNAL SERVER ERROR
```

Comment: The error message returns an HTTP error 500 which means internal server error. So, most probably there is an error on the server. I'd try again later.  If you check out the ulr mldata.org you will see it is currently unavailable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Late to the party, but i had the same error and my simple solution was to run the two commands separately, like:

```
from sklearn import datasets
```

and make sure you run this in a separate line in jupyter notebook

```
mnist_data = datasets.fetch_mldata('MNIST original', data_home = 'datasets/')
```

Comment: This actually works, am surprised. Wonder how this is different from running both the commands from the same cell?

Answer (score 5):

I also had the same error and had to turn off the firewall.  On the Macbook, go System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Firewall > Turn Off Firewall.

Comment: I suggest everyone who is running into this error try this first. All these other workarounds might work but disabling your firewall for this is easier.

Answer (score 4):

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_mldata
try:
    mnist = fetch_mldata('MNIST original')
except Exception as ex:        
    from six.moves import urllib
    from scipy.io import loadmat
    import os

    mnist_path = os.path.join(".", "datasets", "mnist-original.mat")

    # download dataset from github.
    mnist_alternative_url = "https://github.com/amplab/datascience-sp14/raw/master/lab7/mldata/mnist-original.mat"
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(mnist_alternative_url)
    with open(mnist_path, "wb") as f:
        content = response.read()
        f.write(content)

    mnist_raw = loadmat(mnist_path)
    mnist = {
        "data": mnist_raw["data"].T,
        "target": mnist_raw["label"][0],
        "COL_NAMES": ["label", "data"],
        "DESCR": "mldata.org dataset: mnist-original",
    }
    print("Done!")
```

Comment: This answer is all code.  Please add some explanation and amplifying info.

Comment: First time I ran this code all worked perfectly, but after opening jupyter and running it again it gave me the following error:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '.\\datasets\\mnist-original.mat'

Answer (score 3):

I also get the same error as you. Here are some possible solutions that do not require this server.

If you have `tensorflow` installed, you can get MNIST data in the following way:

```
import tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist.input_data as input_data
m=input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST")
```

Then for example `len(m.train.images)` is 55000.

If you don't have tensorflow, you can get this dataset using the instructions [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-mnist/).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative location to download the MNIST dataset (referenced from https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml/blob/master/03_classification.ipynb)

```
from six.moves import urllib
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_mldata
try:
    mnist = fetch_mldata('MNIST original')
except urllib.error.HTTPError as ex:
    print("Could not download MNIST data from mldata.org, trying alternative...")

    # Alternative method to load MNIST, if mldata.org is down
    from scipy.io import loadmat
    mnist_alternative_url = "https://github.com/amplab/datascience-sp14/raw/master/lab7/mldata/mnist-original.mat"
    mnist_path = "./mnist-original.mat"
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(mnist_alternative_url)
    with open(mnist_path, "wb") as f:
        content = response.read()
        f.write(content)
    mnist_raw = loadmat(mnist_path)
    mnist = {
        "data": mnist_raw["data"].T,
        "target": mnist_raw["label"][0],
        "COL_NAMES": ["label", "data"],
        "DESCR": "mldata.org dataset: mnist-original",
    }
    print("Success!")
```

Answer (score 1):

Found a good solution here: https://github.com/Lasagne/Lasagne/blob/master/examples/mnist.py

It downloads dataset from Yan LeCun's website (http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/).

```python
import os
from urllib import urlretrieve

def download(filename, source='http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/'):
    print("Downloading %s" % filename)
    urlretrieve(source + filename, filename)

# We then define functions for loading MNIST images and labels.
# For convenience, they also download the requested files if needed.
import gzip

def load_mnist_images(filename):
    if not os.path.exists(filename):
        download(filename)
    # Read the inputs in Yann LeCun's binary format.
    with gzip.open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        data = np.frombuffer(f.read(), np.uint8, offset=16)
    # The inputs are vectors now, we reshape them to monochrome 2D images,
    # following the shape convention: (examples, channels, rows, columns)
    data = data.reshape(-1, 1, 28, 28)
    # The inputs come as bytes, we convert them to float32 in range [0,1].
    # (Actually to range [0, 255/256], for compatibility to the version
    # provided at http://deeplearning.net/data/mnist/mnist.pkl.gz.)
    return data / np.float32(256)

def load_mnist_labels(filename):
    if not os.path.exists(filename):
        download(filename)
    # Read the labels in Yann LeCun's binary format.
    with gzip.open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        data = np.frombuffer(f.read(), np.uint8, offset=8)
    # The labels are vectors of integers now, that's exactly what we want.
    return data


X_train = load_mnist_images('train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz')
y_train = load_mnist_labels('train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz')
X_test = load_mnist_images('t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz')
y_test = load_mnist_labels('t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz')
```

Answer (score 0):

this is for python 3.6.*

```
import os
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
import numpy as np

def download(filename, source='http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/'):
    print("Downloading %s" % filename)
    urlretrieve(source + filename, filename)

# We then define functions for loading MNIST images and labels.
# For convenience, they also download the requested files if needed.
import gzip

def load_mnist_images(filename):
    if not os.path.exists(filename):
        download(filename)
    # Read the inputs in Yann LeCun's binary format.
    with gzip.open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        data = np.frombuffer(f.read(), np.uint8, offset=16)
    # The inputs are vectors now, we reshape them to monochrome 2D images,
    # following the shape convention: (examples, channels, rows, columns)
    data = data.reshape(-1, 1, 28, 28)
    # The inputs come as bytes, we convert them to float32 in range [0,1].
    # (Actually to range [0, 255/256], for compatibility to the version
    # provided at http://deeplearning.net/data/mnist/mnist.pkl.gz.)
    return data / np.float32(256)

def load_mnist_labels(filename):
    if not os.path.exists(filename):
        download(filename)
    # Read the labels in Yann LeCun's binary format.
    with gzip.open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        data = np.frombuffer(f.read(), np.uint8, offset=8)
    # The labels are vectors of integers now, that's exactly what we want.
    return data


X_train = load_mnist_images('train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz')
y_train = load_mnist_labels('train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz')
X_test = load_mnist_images('t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz')
y_test = load_mnist_labels('t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz')
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution on https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml/issues/7 and this one was most useful for me. Just download the file from https://github.com/amplab/datascience-sp14/raw/master/lab7/mldata/mnist-original.mat

after that use this script:

```
from scipy.io import loadmat
mnist_path = "my/local/path/mnist-original.mat" #type the directory where you want to the file is located
mnist_raw = loadmat(mnist_path)
mnist = {
"data": mnist_raw["data"].T,
"target": mnist_raw["label"][0],
"COL_NAMES": ["label", "data"],
"DESCR": "mldata.org dataset: mnist-original",
}
print("Success!")
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you go to this link:

https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/mnist

Follow the instructions:

1. Open Anaconda Prompt
2. Type conda install -c conda-forge mnist
3. Type conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 mnist

I had the same problem too, I followed these instructions and I don't have any errors again. 
Hope this is helpful. Sorry if this doesn't solve your problem.