# Cannot get MNIST dataset through Tensorflow on Anaconda

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, mnist

I am trying to obtain MNIST dataset through Tensorflow as following.

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
data = input_data.read_data_sets("data/MNIST/", one_hot=True)
```

As title, I installed Tensorflow on Anaconda (Linux) and the package version is *tensorflow 1.8.0*
(Refer: https://anaconda.org/anaconda/tensorflow)

But here are the error messages:

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.examples'; 'tensorflow' is not a package
```

Is it because the tensorflow version is too old to download MNIST ?

I also found the related question: [Cannot get MNIST database through Anaconda/jupyter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43149272/cannot-get-mnist-database-through-anaconda-jupyter)
But this is to download MNIST via sklearn.Is it possible to download through tensorflow on Anaconda?

Comment: Don't name your program "tensorflow.py".

Comment: @xdurch0 Got it! There is another file named "tensorflow.py" in the same directory.... Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two possible reasons for above error:

1. Your file name is **tensorflow.py**, as already pointed out by xdurch0
2. There is another python file in the same directory, named **tensorflow.py**. If it exists, simple remove it.